# Hibernate many-to-one delete only child

Tags: java, hibernate

Where are a lot of similar topics but i still can't handle it myself, sorry. 
So, i have object **"Bank"** which is a parent of an **"Office"**. 
I am trying to delete single Office, but then i do it, all **offices** of parent **bank** are being deleted.
Here's the code:
**Bank**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BANKS")
public class Bank {
    public Bank() {
    }

    public Bank(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bank", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BANK_ID")
    private List<Office> officeList;
```

**Office**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OFFICES")
public class Office {
    public Office() {
    }

    public Office(String city, String address, String workingHours, Bank bank) {
        this.city = city;
        this.address = address;
        this.workingHours = workingHours;
        this.bank = bank;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BANK_ID")
    private Bank bank;

    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "WORKING_HOURS")
    private String workingHours;
```

And **OfficeDAO**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class OfficeDAOImpl implements OfficeDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public Office getByOffice_ID(int Office_ID) {
        return (Office) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Office.class, Office_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Office> getAllOffice() {
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Office.class);
        return criteria.list();
    }

    @Override
    public int save(Office Office) {
        return (Integer) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(Office);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Office Office) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(Office);
    }

    @Override
    public void view(Office Office) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(Office);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int Office_ID) {
        Office s = getByOffice_ID(Office_ID);
        System.out.println("trying to delete" + Office_ID);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(s);
    }

}
```

Hibernate query trace then deleting only office:

```
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from banks where id=?
```

What am i doing wrong? Any advice will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

If i delete **cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE** from office, hibernate won't send any delete request.

Comment: Maybe is the CascadeAll that you have in the OneToMany relationship? I'm not sure 100% that's why I leave you the comment.

Comment: Your mapping looks ok. Except `@JoinColumn(name = "BANK_ID")   private List<Office> officeList;`. You don't need `@JoinColumn` there. Please, add more `delete` related code.

Comment: @v.ladynev, thanks for the advice. If i delete joinColumn annotation, hibernate will create table bank_office, this is inappropriate. This delete snippet is only one, i don't have another delete code.

Comment: @SHaaD You need to add  `mappedBy` to `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bank", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true) private List<Office> officeList;` `@JoinColumn` on the owner side is not commonly used, It is appropriate for unidirectional associations only (without a property at the 'Office` side).

Comment: @v.ladynev, Thanks, now mapping works fine, but without cascade.all at office, it still deletes nothing, but if i add cascade.all it removes all offices at owner bank and bank itself...

Answer (score 1):

You should to configure `CascadeType` in wright way...

`All` - is not the best choice in your case. Try `DETACH` or `REMOVE`. It should help :)

More about [CascadeType can be found here](http://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/).

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue. It looks like hibernate can't remove child entity while it is in parent list, so just add this to delete method in office:

```
s.getBank().getOfficeList().remove(s);
```

And yeah, **Cascade.Remove** at office should not exist.

Comment: Maybe, the reason was `EAGER` in the `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)  private Bank bank;`. Because of `bank` had a deleted office in the list.

Comment: @v.ladynev I know this is late, but I had a similar issue and changing EAGER to LAZY from child entity fixed the issue. But I can't understand the logic behind it. Can u please explain it a bit or provide a reference ?

Comment: @psaw.mora I added explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/55453103/3405171

Comment: `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` default is `EAGER`

Answer (score 0):

An explanation why we have such behavior.

`Bank` is a parent of the `officeList`, so that makes sense to delete `officeList`if we delete `Bank`.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinColumn(name = "BANK_ID")
private Bank bank;
```

This annotation means that `Office` is a parent of `Bank` too

So if we delete `Office` -> we should delete `Bank` -> we should delete all offices of the `Bank` and the `Bank` itself.

We see it in the logs

```
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from offices where id=?
Hibernate: delete from banks where id=?
```

Also we can't use `@JoinColumn` here, if we have `mappedBy` (with Hibernate 5).

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bank", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "BANK_ID")
private List<Office> officeList;
```

Comment: So why making Eager to Lazy fix the issue ? I don't get that part

Comment: @psaw.mora I tried to remove `EAGER` with Hibernate 5. It didn't help. What version of Hibernate do you use?